# Htaccess - Add .html when needed - Wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress, .htaccess

I want to add .html extension to all pages that are not finishing with this extension. I want to do it when the page with .html exists.
I have tried with a lot of code that I have seen and nothing worked on this sense.Maybe there are something different than htaccess to do this.
The only thing that I got was to put .html extension when the page finishes with /.
The web is make with wordpress so if you know any plugin or something that can do this please tell me :)

My initial code in .htaccess is:

```
# Do not do anything for already existing files and folders
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule .+ - [L]

# add .html file extension (if such file does exist)
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])/?$ $1.html [L,QSA]
```

Thanks a lot for your answers!

Comment: You'll want to make sure a `RewriteCond` tests for `-f` "is a file". That's your hint ;)

Comment: Next time when you ask, add the code you've tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that there are several times that I don´t need the extension so I found a wordpress plugin that can do this and I also used a small function in php that checks the words in url to add or not the .html extension.

The name of the plugin I have used is:

Append extensions on Pages by [dr.code.skm](http://dr.code.skm)

The function is similar to this:

```
function my_page_template_redirect()
{
    global $wp;
    $current_url = home_url(add_query_arg(array(),$wp->request));   
    if ( !strpos($current_url, '.html') && !strpos($current_url, 'wp-admin') && !strpos($current_url, 'wp-login') ) {
        if(!is_front_page()){
            wp_safe_redirect( $current_url.'.html' );   
        }       
    }   
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'my_page_template_redirect' );
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: The solution works for pages, however it creating issue while preview the post. How overcome that ?

Comment: Sorry @sumitchauhan but I didn't use the previews on that project so for me worked like a charm.

Answer (score 3):

Quite simply:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
# If /foo/bar does not exist as a file (and)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# If /foo/bar does not exist as a directory (and)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# If /foo/bar.html exists as a file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
# If above three conditions match, append .html
# stopping any other rewrite rules below this (L=last)
# and adding query string (QSA=Query String Append) such as ?a=b&c=d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /$1.html [L,QSA]
```

Comment: This is not working! Thanks for your answer but when I write the URL without the .html extension it returns me to 404.

Comment: Does the url match all the conditions as written in the comments?

Comment: The problem is that the file with html extension does not exists. I am working with wordpress and I think that I have to do one regular expression to each case. Do you know how to do regular expressions in .httaccess ?

Comment: You stated otherwise, "I want to do it when the page with .html exists". If you're using wordpress you only need to change the permalink structure (settings > permalinks). Wordpress routes any request that doesn't exist on the server physically in order to server the proper pages. If you change the permalink, wordpress will update the hyperlinks in the menu's automatically.

Comment: I know, I have added the extension .html to all the pages but what I want is that when the URL has not the .html extension and exists with the .html , I want to redirect it to the URL with .html